# Get all data containing 2 status but not just one of them: SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm working on a query where I want it to show me all the data with 2 specific status only: `ORGNSCN` and `TRANSITRCV` - and that `TRANSITRCV` was there first before the `ORGNSCN`.

See the sample data here:

[image]

So I should get `InvoiceNumber FCI150142`.

I created a query:

```
SELECT [InvoiceNumber], [StageID] 
FROM [CARGODB].[dbo].[BoxesUpdateLog] 
WHERE [StageID] = 'ORGNSCN' AND 
      [StageID] = 'TRANSITRCV') 
GROUP BY [InvoiceNumber], [StageID];
```

My thinking with above is, it will show me the all the data containing those 2 status at least (no dates first) but it displays nothing.

What am I missing?

**UPDATE:**

I created a query which gives me all the data with both of the status but I can't figure out how to get all the data where `TRANSITRCV` was entered first before `ORGNSCN`:

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT [InvoiceNumber], 
       MAX(Case When [StageID] = 'ORGNSCN' Then 1 else 0 end) as [ORGNSCN], 
       MAX(Case When [StageID] = 'TRANSITRCV' Then 1 else 0 end) as [TRANSITRCV]
FROM [CARGODB].[dbo].[BoxesUpdateLog] WHERE [StageID] in ( 'ORGNSCN','TRANSITRCV')
GROUP BY [InvoiceNumber]
) x
WHERE [ORGNSCN] > 0 and 
      [TRANSITRCV] > 0
```

**UPDATE: (sample data)**

```
RecordID    InvoiceNumber   DatePosted                  TransDate               StageID     Status
31478801    FCI150142       2018-04-18  10:30:35.000    2018-04-18 10:30:35.000 TRANSITRCV  RECEIVED
31478851    FCI150142       2018-04-18  11:33:53.330    2018-04-18 11:33:53.330 LOADCNTNR   LOADED
31488281    FCI150142       2018-04-19  09:28:41.000    2018-04-19 09:28:41.000 ORGNSCN     ORIGIN SCAN
31602071    FCI150142       2018-05-01  15:05:20.000    2018-04-19 15:05:20.000 S000000001  RECEIVED
31602883    FCI150142       2018-05-01  15:06:14.000    2018-04-25 15:06:14.000 S000000005  LOADED
31603695    FCI150142       2018-05-01  15:06:37.000    2018-04-28 15:06:37.000 S000000006  DEPARTED
```

Your help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Table script and some sample data would be very helpful to figure out the query. And what column will decide the `TRANSITRCV was there first before the ORGNSCN` is that `DatePosted` ??

Comment: HIi @Susang, yes `DatePosted`

Comment: Can you please post table script and sample data in text instead of image so that we can copy and workout ?

Comment: @jeepers_creepers, Try my Answer. Hope that helps you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this Answer:

**Table Schema:**

```
DECLARE @BoxesUpdateLog TABLE(RecordId BIGINT, [InvoiceNumber] VARCHAR(15), DatePosted DATETIME, TransDate DATETIME, StageID VARCHAR(25), Status VARCHAR(25))

INSERT INTO @BoxesUpdateLog VALUES
(31478801,'FCI150142','2018-04-18  10:30:35.000','2018-04-18 10:30:35.000','TRANSITRCV','RECEIVED   ')
,(31478851,'FCI150142','2018-04-18  11:33:53.330','2018-04-18 11:33:53.330','LOADCNTNR ','LOADED        ')
,(31488281,'FCI150142','2018-04-19  09:28:41.000','2018-04-19 09:28:41.000','ORGNSCN   ','ORIGIN SCAN')
,(31602071,'FCI150142','2018-05-01  15:05:20.000','2018-04-19 15:05:20.000','S000000001','RECEIVED  ')
,(31602883,'FCI150142','2018-05-01  15:06:14.000','2018-04-25 15:06:14.000','S000000005','LOADED        ')
,(31603695,'FCI150142','2018-05-01  15:06:37.000','2018-04-28 15:06:37.000','S000000006','DEPARTED  ')
```

**Query:**

```
SELECT [InvoiceNumber]
FROM [CARGODB].[dbo].[BoxesUpdateLog] 
WHERE [StageID] in ( 'ORGNSCN','TRANSITRCV')
GROUP BY [InvoiceNumber]
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT [StageID])=2
    AND MAX(CASE WHEN [StageID] = 'ORGNSCN' THEN DatePosted END) > MAX(CASE WHEN [StageID] = 'TRANSITRCV' THEN DatePosted END)
```

**OutPut:**

```
InvoiceNumber
FCI150142
```

Check the result in the [#SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/cfb00/1)

Answer (score 0):

You are using `'And'` in your query after where clause , which won't be ever true.
Use `'Or'`, or `'IN'`

**OR**

```
SELECT [InvoiceNumber], [StageID] FROM [CARGODB].[dbo].[BoxesUpdateLog] WHERE [StageID] = 'ORGNSCN' OR [StageID] = 'TRANSITRCV' GROUP BY [InvoiceNumber], [StageID];
```

**IN**

```
SELECT [InvoiceNumber], [StageID] FROM [CARGODB].[dbo].[BoxesUpdateLog] WHERE [StageID] IN ( 'ORGNSCN' , 'TRANSITRCV') GROUP BY [InvoiceNumber], [StageID];
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer @Paras, but using `OR` or `IN` means I'll get all the data with any of the status that I need but not both, right?

Comment: Yes, the status could either be ORGNSCN or TRANSITRCV at a time for a tupple .
IN or using OR would ensure to return all those tupples with either 'ORGNSCN' or 'TRANSITRCV'.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'DatePosted'column in ORDER BY Clause, that would lead to a sorted result set ordered by the dates these records were posted.